# Eigenvalues of $2\times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What are the eigenvalues of $A^3$ if
$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 1           \\[0.3em]
      1 & 1 \\[0.3em]
     \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$ and $2$ with corresponding eigenvectors $v_0=(1,-1)$ and $v_2=(1,1)$, respectively.  Then $A^3v_0=0v_0$ and $A^3v_2=A^2(2v_2)=\dots=8v_2$, so $A^3$ has eigenvalues $0$ and $8$.

As Samuel Coskey hints, there is a more general principle behind this.

Answer (score 4):

A question you might wish to answer first: What is the relationship between the eigenvalues of $A$ and the eigenvalues of $A^3$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Lets $\lambda$ an aigenvalue of $A$,there is some non ull vector $v$ such that $Av=\lambda v$, so:

$$
A^3 v=AA(Av)=AA(\lambda v) =\lambda AA v= \lambda A(Av)= \lambda A \lambda v =......
$$
con you complete? and find the eigenvalues of $A$ ?